# How to stop an animation loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I have a problem with the animation on this page ["intervista 5"](http://www.triridemtb.com/close-up/intervista-cinque/)

Practically, when the player is playing, next and prev arrows should be hidden.
When the user hovers with the mouse on `div.interview_media` the function I created[1] shows current slide's active arrows.

**Now, the issue**: if I hover `div.interview_media` from the right or the left side of the div, centrally (i.e. where the next or the prev arrow should be) the animation enters a loop since when the arrow is hidden, the pointer triggers the animation while, appearing the arrow, the pointer is no more on `div.interview_media` but on one of the arrow (`.browse`) so arrows are hidden entering, then, a show/hide loop… doh!

Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Thank you all for you help,
Giuseppe

[1] The show hide function:

```
$(function(){
    $('.interview_media').hover(
        function(){
            console.log('showing arrows');
            $('.hidden').stop(true, true).show(200);
        },
        function(){
            console.log('hiding arrows');
            $('.hidden').stop(true, true).hide(200);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the left and right buttons inside the .interview_media div. This way, jQuery understands that you are not leaving the .interview_media div every time you hover over the right and left buttons.

Comment: Hi Lamariffic, thanks a lot for your answer. Unluckily, being  absolute positioned, next and previous arrows have to be outside the single slide container .interview_media which is a container needed, instead, for each slide. It would not be possible to create next and previous arrows for each slide.

Comment: Well, that makes everything a bit harder. You can either move the <a> elements dynamically inside each .interview_media. However, I would suggest adding a div container that has both .interview_media AND the buttons, then applying the .hover function to it. I can walk you through those options if you're having problems.

Comment: Hi Lamarrific, thanks again. 

What about if we move the arrows inside `.interview_media` and dynamically remove them from current slide and add them to the next one (if any)? I would like to avoid to show them move left or right with any slide transition, we could hide them on each click. 

What do you think about it?

Comment: Hi Lamarrific, I found out that using fadeIn/Out instead of show/hide functions works better almost never triggering the loop. Even if that works, I really don't feel like the bug has been fixed. Would you mind to help me to remove and add dynamically arrows from each slide as you proposed?

Comment: Ok, I took the pragmatic way I should had get yesterday. I just moved next and prev arrows inside `.interview_media` as suggested by Lamarrific (thank you mate) and I don't mind about the moving arrows. Time is precious.